# Python Azure Function deployment succeeds, emulation works, but getting application error

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have a Python Azure Function that I've deployed to successfully in the past. Recently, I can't get any deployed code to respond. I'm simply getting ":( Application Error". I haven't found any of the logs useful, but this particular part stood out to me:

```
/home/LogFiles/2023_07_13_lw1sdlwk000475_docker.log  (https://gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2023_07_13_lw1sdlwk000475_docker.log)
2023-07-13T15:23:26.437Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 30.6934132 sec
2023-07-13T15:23:41.830Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 46.0863162 sec
2023-07-13T15:23:57.127Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 61.3830012 sec
2023-07-13T15:24:15.070Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 79.3262565 sec
2023-07-13T15:24:30.663Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 94.9192177 sec
2023-07-13T15:24:45.939Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 110.1949702 sec
2023-07-13T15:25:02.172Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de. Elapsed time = 126.4275622 sec
2023-07-13T15:25:07.455Z ERROR - Container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de for site gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func has exited, failing site start
2023-07-13T15:25:07.511Z ERROR - Container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2023-07-13T15:25:07.551Z INFO  - Stopping site gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func because it failed during startup.
```

I haven't configured any extra networking information, so I'm not sure why that's happening. I'm retrieving that log from the KUDU log stream.

If it helps, this is my `host.json`. It's the default and it hasn't changed since the inception of the project.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "concurrency": {
        "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
        "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:30:00",
    "healthMonitor": {
        "enabled": true,
        "healthCheckInterval": "00:00:10",
        "healthCheckWindow": "00:02:00",
        "healthCheckThreshold": 6,
        "counterThreshold": 0.80
    },
    "logging": {
        "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Information"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20,
                "evaluationInterval": "01:00:00",
                "initialSamplingPercentage": 100.0,
                "samplingPercentageIncreaseTimeout": "00:00:01",
                "samplingPercentageDecreaseTimeout": "00:00:01",
                "minSamplingPercentage": 0.1,
                "maxSamplingPercentage": 100.0,
                "movingAverageRatio": 1.0,
                "excludedTypes": "Dependency;Event",
                "includedTypes": "PageView;Trace"
            },
            "enableLiveMetrics": true
        }
    },
    "watchDirectories": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have any advice or routes for me to diagnose the issue?

Additional useful information:

- I can emulate this just fine using Azurite and the VS Code tools.
- I was able, this morning, to successfully deploy an old version of the code, but that seemed to be short-lived and inconsistent.
- The deployment always succeeds. It's trying to reach the deployment that I can't seem to do.
- I am not deploying a container. I'm using a Linux app service plan with an Azure Function. I'm ZIP deploying to that Azure Function my Python project.

**Addition 1:**
FiddleStix pointed out as comment that I could find logs in App Insights. This is what I found

```
System.NullReferenceException:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WorkerFunctionMetadataProvider+<GetFunctionMetadataAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/WorkerFunctionMetadataProvider.cs:79)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.FunctionMetadataProvider+<GetFunctionMetadataAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FunctionMetadataProvider.cs:45)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.FunctionMetadataManager.LoadFunctionMetadata (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FunctionMetadataManager.cs:145)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.FunctionMetadataManager.GetFunctionMetadata (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/FunctionMetadataManager.cs:89)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.GetFunctionsMetadata (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs:370)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost+<InitializeAsync>d__94.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs:286)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost+<StartAsyncCore>d__93.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Host/ScriptHost.cs:258)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host+<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebJobsScriptHostService+<UnsynchronizedStartHostAsync>d__52.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=4.22.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebJobsScriptHostService.cs:328)
```

[image]

Comment: I find that the best logs are usually in the application insights exceptions list. In portal.azure.com, you get to it via `my-function-page -> Application Insights -> Failures -> Exceptions -> Top 3 exception types` and click the exception type to get a list of actual exceptions. In that list, you should be able to find some Python tracebacks. If you aren't sure what the tracebacks are telling you, please add one to your question.

Comment: Oh damn, I had no idea it would publish logs there for deployment errors. I'll add to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after much trial and error. You need to [enable remote builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=manual%2Cbash&pivots=python-mode-configuration#enable-remote-build) for the `requirements.txt` to be installed. In addition, `.funcignore` [apparently](https://github.com/Azure/functions-action/issues/62) [doesn't](https://github.com/Azure/functions-action/issues/36) [work](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1745) as you would expect it to. I switched to [using a `.artifactignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-artifactignore) to ignore possibly error-causing files like `local.settings.json-sample`. Once I did both of these things, I no longer received runtime errors.

Comment: It's unrelated to any solution, but it's also important to note that [Microsoft recommends hand-crafting your `requirements.txt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=manual%2Cbash&pivots=python-mode-configuration#handcraft-requirementstxt). Freezing your versions can cause issues, too.

Answer (score 1):

- *Application Error* occurs due to many reasons.
- But as per your provided logs, it could be due to port issue:

> 2023-07-13T15:25:07.511Z ERROR - Container gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func_1_38c6d5de didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
> 2023-07-13T15:25:07.551Z INFO  - Stopping site gridinspector-dev-eus2-python-func because it failed during startup.

One workaround to fix this issue is *exposing the PORT 80* in app settings:
Navigate to your `function app=> Open Settings=>Configuration=>Add New Application Settings`:

- Add the setting `WEBSITES_PORT`**:**`80`

[image]

- And to track application logs, enable application logging in Function `App=> Monitoring=>App Service Logs=> Select File System` in Application Logging.

[image]

- You can see the real-time logs in `LogStream` of function app.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Though it was not the cause of my error, it helped me track down the culprit.